# Unknown scope Amazon Ads API

Tags: c#, amazon-advertising-api

I am trying to create an authorization grant to the Amazon ads API:

https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/getting-started/create-authorization-grant

Here is the URL that I use:

https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id=X&scope=advertising::campaign_management&response_type=code&redirect_uri=hX

I get this error:

Error Summary
400 Bad Request
An unknown scope was requested

I want to download this report:

https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/reporting/v3/overview

What scope do I need?

Answer (score 0):

I need to apply for API access as a partner. I used the wrong client ID: https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/onboarding/apply-for-access